# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 Report Builder User Access Permissions

Tags: permissions, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've just set up SSRS for my office.  Some users need to be able to run Report Builder.  I've created an AD global group and used Report Manager to assign Report Builder privileges to that group.

I've verified that the Report Builder configuration on SSRS is correct.

Even after these users are assigned to the Report Builder role, the link for Report Builder does not show up when they login to Report Manager.

I've tried having them download Report Builder by providing them the link directly; when they download it and try and execute a report, there is a message saying that the user does not have permissions for this (despite the fact that I've explicitly given them permissions earlier).

The only users who CAN actually run ReportBuilder when assigned that role are Local Admins or Domain Admins.

It isn't realistic for me to assign Local Admin privileges for anyone who wants to do ad-hoc reporting.  I must be missing something.  Is there a folder these users need access to on the file system?  Or perhaps something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: I should add that I am seeing this in the log file:

Comment: rshost!rshost!29f4!09/16/2010-17:53:09:: i INFO: Endpoint 4 is disabled and no url is registered vdir=/ReportServer/ReportBuilder, pdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder

Comment: also the service account is Network Service

Answer (score 0):

I had to ensure that the user who needed access to report builder had the privledge to the "Execute report definitions" task at the system level.  I did this by creating a new system role (I named it "System Report Builder Access") and enabling just that one task.  I then applied the role to the necessary user.

Hope that helps..